# Resample 2D numpy array to arbitrary dimensions

Tags: python, arrays

I am looking for a way to rescale a numpy 2D array to arbitrary dimensions in such a way that each cell in the rescaled array contains a weighted mean of all the cells that it (partially) covers.

I have found several methods to do this if the new dimensions are multiples of the original dimensions. For example, given a 4x4 array, this can be rescaled into a 2x2 array where the first cell is the mean of the 4 top-left cells in the original etc. But none of these methods seem to work for example when going from a 4x4 array to a 3x3 array.

This image illustrates what I'd like to do in the case of going from 4x4 (black grid) to 3x3 (red grid):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iutym4frcphcef2/regrid.png?dl=0

Cell (0,0) in the smaller array covers the entire cell (0,0) and parts of cells (1,0), (0,1) and (1,1). I'd like the new cell to contain the mean of these cells weighted by the areas of the yellow, green, blue and orange regions.

Is there a way in to do this with numpy/scipy? Is there a name for this type of regridding (that would help when searching for a method)?

Comment: What you are talking about is called interpolation, there are several ways to do it in numpy/scipy. [Here is one of them](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#two-dimensional-spline-representation-procedural-bisplrep) (edit: updated the link to a better example)

Comment: I've already been experimenting with several interpolation methods, but none of them are giving me the results I described.

Comment: What you're describing is exactly interpolation though, you just have to decide whether you want it to be linear, or with splines, or some other metric.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `linear interpolation` will give you the weighted mean you desire.

Comment: I don't think it will. Linear interpolation gives the mean in a point weighted by the distances to neighbouring grid points. What I want is the mean weighted by the areas covered by the new cells, as illustrated in the figure. This is the same thing in some instances (like the 4x4->2x2 downsampling), but not in other cases (like 4x4->3x3).

Comment: Ah yes. Are you taking each entry of the original array as the value for the entire cell, rather than just at the point?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my first post.

Comment: It's a pretty non standard thing to do, you might have to just write your own function to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:#

It uses the [`Interval`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval) package to easily calculate the overlaps of the cells of the different grids, so you'll need to grab that.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
from interval import Interval, IntervalSet

def overlap(rect1, rect2):
  """Calculate the overlap between two rectangles"""
  xInterval = Interval(rect1[0][0], rect1[1][0]) & Interval(rect2[0][0], rect2[1][0])
  yInterval = Interval(rect1[0][1], rect1[1][1]) & Interval(rect2[0][1], rect2[1][1])
  area = (xInterval.upper_bound - xInterval.lower_bound) * (yInterval.upper_bound - yInterval.lower_bound)
  return area


def meanInterp(data, m, n):

  newData = numpy.zeros((m,n))
  mOrig, nOrig = data.shape

  hBoundariesOrig, vBoundariesOrig = numpy.linspace(0,1,mOrig+1), numpy.linspace(0,1,nOrig+1)
  hBoundaries, vBoundaries = numpy.linspace(0,1,m+1), numpy.linspace(0,1,n+1)

  for iOrig in range(mOrig):
    for jOrig in range(nOrig):
      for i in range(m):
        if hBoundaries[i+1] <= hBoundariesOrig[iOrig]: continue
        if hBoundaries[i] >= hBoundariesOrig[iOrig+1]: break
        for j in range(n):
          if vBoundaries[j+1] <= vBoundariesOrig[jOrig]: continue
          if vBoundaries[j] >= vBoundariesOrig[jOrig+1]: break

          boxCoords = ((hBoundaries[i], vBoundaries[j]),(hBoundaries[i+1], vBoundaries[j+1]))
          origBoxCoords = ((hBoundariesOrig[iOrig], vBoundariesOrig[jOrig]),(hBoundariesOrig[iOrig+1], vBoundariesOrig[jOrig+1]))

          newData[i][j] += overlap(boxCoords, origBoxCoords) * data[iOrig][jOrig] / (hBoundaries[1] * vBoundaries[1])

  return newData



fig = pyplot.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

m1, n1 = 37,59
m2, n2 = 10,13

dataGrid1 = numpy.random.rand(m1, n1)
dataGrid2 = meanInterp(dataGrid1, m2, n2)

mat1 = ax1.matshow(dataGrid1, cmap="YlOrRd")
mat2 = ax2.matshow(dataGrid2, cmap="YlOrRd")

#make both plots square
ax1.set_aspect(float(n1)/float(m1))
ax2.set_aspect(float(n2)/float(m2))



pyplot.show()
```

Here are a couple of examples with differing grids:

[image: 2x2 grid mapped to a 5x5 grid]

[image: 3x2 grid mapped to 5x7]

[image: 5x5-59x59]

Down sampling is possible too.
[image: 37x69-10x13]

After having done this, i'm pretty sure all i've done is some form of [image sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling). If you're looking to do this on large lists, then you're going to need to make things a bit more efficient, as it will be pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to be what I am looking for, although as you say, I will probably have to implement this in C or something to get acceptable performance.

Comment: I was also looking at image sampling algorithms before. There may be some algorithm that does exactly this, but I wasn't able to find it. I would still be interested to know if there is a name for this type of resampling.